# ubuntu 18.04 node js 12.13.0 (sapper?) Date.toLocaleString failing on 'CET'

Tags: node.js, datetime, ubuntu, locale

node.js code:

```
var date = new Date();
var today = date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE', { timeZone: 'CET' });
```

Error:

```
var today = date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE', { timeZone: 'CET' });/*
                 ^
RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: CET
  at Date.toLocaleDateString (<anonymous>)
```

`locale` command for the machine gives:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Removing the `timezone` parameter from the call to `toLocaleDateString` returns the time in US format not SE format:

i.e. `var today = date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');` gives: `3/26/2022`

What's going on? The SE locale is on my machine; the `toLocaleDateString('sv-SE', { timeZone: 'CET' })` command give the expected results in e.g. a Chrome console on the same machine, so it appears to be a node problem.

My app is a `sapper` build, but I can't imagine that is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Seems like my version of node doesn't have `full-icu` (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500) I shall work on trying to get full-icu installed and working and report back ...

Answer (score 0):

Version 12.13.0 of node only has US locale available by default.

I installed package `full-icu` for my app: `npm i full-icu`

I then had to modify the calls in `package.json`:

script `dev` became `"env NODE_ICU_DATA=./node_modules/full-icu sapper dev"`

script `start` became `"node --icu-data-dir=./node_modules/full-icu __sapper__/build"`

I also had to modify the `date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE', { timeZone: 'CET' })` call to be `date.toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');` because `CET` still doesn't exist for whatever reason ...

(Ideally I'd update `node`, but for a reason I have forgotten, newer versions of node collide with some critical package in my app).